# Change checked value of bootstrap-checkbox plugin, when submitting form

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, form-submit

I am using [bootstrap-checkbox](https://vsn4ik.github.io/bootstrap-checkbox/) within a html form as follows:

```
<form action= ...>

// some inputs...

<input id="mySwitch" class="switch" type="checkbox" name="mySwitch"
data-off-active-cls="btn-warning"
data-on-active-cls="btn-primary"
data-group-cls="btn-group-sm"
value="1">

//more inputs...

</form>
```

My problem is that when I am submitting the form, the default value for checkbox plugin is `"on"` and I want to change it to something else, e.g `"1"`

I tried to add a `value="1"` property to the input element but I still receive `"on"` as a checked value at the server.

```
//HTTP request output    

array:19 [▼
"_token" => "192q78C3xGUorq0mFQMk7g0VSBcojjvt9ikkWLE4"
  ...
  "mySwitch" => "on" // <-- I want this to be 1
  ...
]
```

Any help appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes will return `on` or `off`, and that's it. They're only designed to return a binary.

If you want to have it return something else, use a different field, or use some JavaScript to change the value of `on` to `1`.